# How to connect two datasources to a related third datasource in client script?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to attach a related datasource.
Datasources are: "Guest"<-->"CheckIn"<-->"Guard"

"Guests" datasource - is displayed in a table with a clickable button on each record. On the button click, create mode is set on a related datasource "CheckIn". "Checkin" has a foreign key to "Guests", it also has a timestamp field. This works as intended.

The problem is, I have another datasource called "Guard". "CheckIn" has a foreign key for "Guard". Since I am doing this with a button click, I am unable to use a list widget to select the "Guard". I have the _key/Id value saved in a session variable for the "Guard". How can I get the correct "Guard" item out of the datasource and set the relation in "CheckIn"? I have been cheating it by setting the _fk field to the "Guard" Id.

Comment: If your Guard key/id is a session variable on the client I would suggest changing this  to the actual guard record and then in your Check-in creation you can just do `datasource.item.Guard = YourSessionVariable;`. But that depends on how your session variable is stored and if it's accessible on the client or not.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa that's what I'd like to do but I'm currently using sessionStorage and it only accepts strings. Is there another way to save the actual guard record? I did figure out how to load the Guard datasource and I did all the updating in the load() callback but this seems like such a needless call. Simply setting the _fk works well but I worry that when it's fully depreciated, I wont have access to it..

Comment: You are correct that once fk is deprecated you probably won’t have access to setting the fk directly and you will need to fetch the record and set the relation equal to the record. You can still use your key/id session store though in your Check In model onBeforeCreate event and do this all server side. Use app.models.Guard.getRecord(YourSessionId) to retrieve the guard record and the set record.Guard = thefetchedrecord.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusMalessa Thats a great way to handle it! However, I can not seem to access the session variable within the server script. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I guess let me ask you how do you assign the session id for Guard key, is it server side or client and please add the necessary code to your question how you set this.

Comment: The Guard _key is stored in sessionStorage("guardID",_key). Instead of using the onBeforeCreate() event,I used a server script that passes the Guest and Guard keys to it via a client function. The server script then creates a new checkIn record and assigns the Guard and Guest items like the above suggestion. Seems to work! Thank you Markus.